# If there is No sin in heaven and God is all love then how could the devil ever have sinned

Tags: sin

Again, it is said that there is no sin in heaven. Jesus also told Mary to not touch him because he had not yet ascended to heaven. But how could the devil had sinned if he only knew God. It would have only been exposure to Love and perfection. It would have been IMPOSSIBLE to know sin in the presence of God if he created you and you could not know evil. I believe in God and Jesus and the Holy Ghost but this question perplexes me. Think about it. Adam and eve didn't know sin until they ate from the apple. How can something created by God and only exposed to heaven where God illuminates with his glory, where there is no crying no suffering,  no imperfections no sickness. Then how could you even conceive the mere idea of sin? You can't cause it would not exist. You wouldn't know about death either cause it would not exist. Can someone please help me with this question.  I don't doubt my faith but it does not make any sense.

Comment: Please don't put personal information in questions.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question, though a good one, is too broad and opinion-based for it to work here. For it to work, you'd need to say what denomination of Christians you want an answer from. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. This question is not asking how God could create evil, but how the devil could have sinned if he only knew God. Though perhaps related, they're not the same question. However, it *is* too broad and opinion-based for the site, since it doesn't ask for the perspective of a particular denomination.

Comment: Christians in general and theologians in particular have struggled for centuries to find satisfying answers to the same (or similar) questions you have raised. The technical name for the conundrum which you describe is "theodicy," which is an explanation (a theory, if you will) which can account for how evil could ever rear its ugly in the paradise which was the Garden of Eden, and well before that in heaven, the very "abode of God"? A good place for you to start finding answers is to do a Google search using the term "theodicy" as your starting point. Then tackle the book of Job!